# If $L$ is an interval and $C$ is convex, is $LC$ convex too?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-geometry, locally-convex-spaces

Let $LC = \{\lambda v \mid \lambda \in L, v \in C\},$ where $C$ is some convex set of the vector space $V.$ If $L$ is an interval, is $LC$ convex?

I thought and assumed so for a while, and some drawings suggested this to be true, however, today I tried to prove it analytically and the proof escaped me.

We start with $\lambda u, \mu v \in L C$ and $t \in (0,1).$ Then $t \mu v + (1-t) \lambda u$...? No clue.

I also tried writing $LC = \bigcup\limits_{\lambda \in L} \lambda C$ which is the union of convex sets; and I know that a tower of convex sets is convex but then I don't know how to prove this family $(\lambda C)_{\lambda \in L}$ is a tower.

Other ideas, suggestions or a counter example appreciated.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $L$? If not, it's not true. See if you can come up with a counterexample where $L = [-1, 1]$, for example. (Misha's nice answer below assumes that $L$ consists of nonnegative numbers.)

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thank you for pointing out that assumption, which I did not notice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, we can continue the same way as you started (assuming, as Izaak van Dongen points out in the comments, that $L$ consists of nonnegative numbers):
$$
   t\mu v + (1-t)\lambda u = (t\mu + (1-t)\lambda)\left(\frac{t\mu}{t\mu + (1-t)\lambda} v + \frac{(1-t)\lambda}{t\mu + (1-t)\lambda} u\right).
$$
Inside the big parentheses, we have a point on the segment $[u,v]$, because $\frac{t\mu}{t\mu + (1-t)\lambda}$ and $\frac{(1-t)\lambda}{t\mu + (1-t)\lambda}$ are two nonnegative weights that add up to $1$. (This is where our assumption about $L$ comes in!) In particular, what we have there is an element of $C$, because $u \in C$ and $v \in C$.

Outside the big parentheses, $(t\mu + (1-t)\lambda)$ is a value somewhere between $\mu$ and $\lambda$. Because both $\mu$ and $\lambda$ are in $L$, we also know that $(t\mu + (1-t)\lambda)$ is in $L$. Therefore the whole expression gives us a point in $LC$.

Comment: I was mainly interested in the case $L = \{-1\}$ or $L \subset [0, \infty).$

Comment: If $L$ is entirely nonpositive, the same argument works.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, I provide a counterexample to my own question, thanks to Izaak van Dongen.

Consider $V = \mathbf{R}^2$ and let $C = \{1\} \times [0,1]$ a convex set. Then $[-1,1]C = [-1,0]C \cup [0,1]C$ consists of two triangles that look like a bowtie at the origin, therefore not convex. (For $c \in C,$ $[0,1]c$ is just the line segment conecting the origin to $c,$ and $[-1,0]c$ is therefore the reflection through the origin of this segment of line. Then $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ does no belong to $[-1,1]C$ but it is the mid point between two of the four corners of $[-1,1]C.$)